# How to expire each element of a collection by setting an individual time-to-live (TTL) property in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, ttl

How to expire each element of a collection by setting an individual time-to-live (TTL) property in Cassandra?

the documentation is here, but I cannot find an example.
(https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useExpire.html)

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Hi @TungD.Nguyen, I am building a cassandra database for persisting Kafka(http://kafka.apache.org/) events and then make some machine learning with the data in Cassandra. **I am still in dev stage**, in this days I will tests this solution with **more than 4 million** entries and will se if there is any problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have different TTL in a same column collection (set, list, map) of cassandra.
Do like in this example:
There is a table -> tableName
whih one column (col1) primary key of text type
A column(col2) of type set <long>

```
UPDATE tableName USING TTL 30 SET col2=col2+{11} WHERE col1=-10;
UPDATE tableName USING TTL 88 SET col2=col2+{22} WHERE col1=-10;
```

In the example I am upserting to values to the set, {11} with TTL=30 and {22} with TTL=88.
When one element exeeds the TTL it is automaticaly deleted.
When all the elements in the set exceeds the TTL and the set is empty, the row is also deleted.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't more upvoted, I couldn't find this information anywhere and here it is... from 2016. Life saver, thanks man!