# Cassandra : How to set individual TTL for elements of a collection (set type to be specific)

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cql3, cqlsh

we have a scenario where we are trying to update data in Cassandra, we have a update query to update multiple fields out of which one field is a of type set(col1 in this scenario) in cassandra.

Update query is something like below -

```
UPDATE <table_name> USING TTL 3600 SET col1=col1+{'test_30'},col2=100 , col3=400 ;
```

**Is there a way TTL can be set only for col1 i.e. the ttl should be for the value "test_30" in the set???**

*The requirement basically is that only value 'test_30' should get deleted after 3600 seconds set as ttl.*

datastax's cql [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useExpire.html) says nothing specific about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388013/apply-ttl-in-column-level

Answer (score 0):

The first issue that I see is that your query is missing the WHERE clause. The update statements must have this clause.

When running this query (after solving the issue mentioned above) you will specify a TTL for element 'test_30' in column col1, col2 and col3 values.

If you want to set the TTL just for 'test_30' you should only have the col1 ([similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166382/how-to-expire-each-element-of-a-collection-by-setting-an-individual-time-to-live)) and not col2 and col3

Also, you should be aware of [CASSANDRA-8877](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8877). Currently is not possible to read the ttl for individual values in a collection. Also if you run `select ttl(col1) from <table name>` you will get an error `Cannot use selection function ttl on collections`

Some additional reading on [CQL update](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html).

Comment: thanks ,i missed out the where clause. we were trying to avoid 2 update but seems that is the only solution for now..

Comment: This is how Cassandra works. I hope that my answer helped out.